# How can "this" of the outer class be accessed from an inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

Is it possible to get a reference to `this` from within a Java inner class?

i.e.

```
class Outer {

  void aMethod() {

    NewClass newClass = new NewClass() {
      void bMethod() {
        // How to I get access to "this" (pointing to outer) from here?
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can access the instance of the outer class like this:

```
Outer.this
```

Answer (score 35):

Outer.this

ie.

```
class Outer {
    void aMethod() {
        NewClass newClass = new NewClass() {
            void bMethod() {
                System.out.println( Outer.this.getClass().getName() ); // print Outer
            }
        };
    }
}
```

BTW In Java class names start with uppercase by convention.

Answer (score 10):

Prepend the outer class's class name to this:

```
outer.this
```

Answer (score 3):

yes you can using outer class name with **this**.
     **outer.this**

Answer (score 1):

Extra: It is not possible when the inner class is declared 'static'.