# This acts on inner Class

Tags: java

I have a Class, which contains inner class.
I want to send value, which equals to the top class, but "this" sends the value of inner class. What can I do?

```
package Controller;
public class MessageFrameListener{
private MessageFrame mf;
private User us;
private Contact cn;
private Timer timer;
private Running run;
private ListFrame lf;

public MessageFrameListener(ListFrame l_f, MessageFrame m_f, User u_s, Contact c_n, Running r_n){
    run = r_n;
    mf = m_f;
    us = u_s;
    cn = c_n;
    lf = l_f;
    m_f.addButtonListener(new SButtonListener());
    m_f.addWinListener(new FrameListener());

    timer = new Timer(500,new timerListener());
    timer.start();
}


public class FrameListener implements WindowListener{

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        timer.stop();
        timer = null;
        mf.close();
        lf.removeMFL(this));
    }       
}
}
```

So, this line

```
        lf.removeMFL(this));
```

sends "FrameListener" by this, but I want to send "MessageFrameListener"

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2731719/1140748

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [qualified `this`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4):

```
MessageFrameListener.this
```

Comment: Ditto. Deleted my answer in favor of this one.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
   lf.removeMFL(MessageFrameListener.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the inner class itself, you can use

```
MessageFrameListener.this;
```

You can also add a method to the outer class

```
public MessageFrameListener getInstance() {
    return this;
}
```