# Using this keyword in abstract context

Tags: java

I came across this pattern in some source codes:

```
public abstract class Foo {

    void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("...");
    }

    private class FooBar extends Foo{
        void doAnything(){
            Foo.this.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Whats the significance of

```
Foo.this.doSomething();
```

or is it just some cargo cult practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`Foo.this` and `this` refer to two different objects.**

Since `FooBar` is an inner class defined inside `Foo`, every instance of `FooBar` has an instance of `Foo` associated with it.

- `this` refers to the `FooBar` instance itself;
- `Foo.this` refers to the outer `Foo` instance.

See [How can "this" of the outer class be accessed from an inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731719/how-can-this-of-the-outer-class-be-accessed-from-an-inner-class)

That said, the `Foo.this.` in the example you show is redundant and can be omitted (unless both `Foo` and `FooBar` have a method called `doSomething()`).

Answer (score 2):

In the example you give this is equivalent to calling `doSomething();` directly.

However, if you declared the same method `void doSomething()` in the `FooBar` class you would use this notation to signify you call the method of the outer class not the inner.

In the latter case `this.doSomething()` would not suffice, this still will point to the `this` member variable of `FooBar`, that is why you specify specifically the class from which you want to call the method.

Answer (score 2):

`Foo.this` references outer class Foo's object instance, which is always bound in inner class's object.

You can think to Foo and FooBar as being instanced always together, when Foo is instantiated.

In your case is not necessary, but if you need to pass the Foo object instance to any method that requires it from the inner Foo.Bar, you can do it with:

```
// some method of some other class (OtherClass.java)
void someFunction( Foo foo )...

// ...
private class FooBar extends Foo{
    void doAnything(){
        otherClass.someFunction( Foo.this );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Foo.this` refers to outer class object,where as `this` refers current class object.
*According to java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).It is also called **Shadowing***