# Why am I throwing no errors for calling object-specific methods/fields from inner classes?

Tags: java, class, inner-classes, instance-methods

I'm using something similar to the following code in one of my Java classes:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int someValue;

    void incrementValue() {
        someValue++;
    }

    public abstract static class InnerClass {
        private final SomeClass toRunOn;

        public InnerClass(SomeClass obj) {
            toRunOn = obj;
        }

        public abstract void execute();

        // To allow us to call this on a given instance
        final SomeClass getObj() {
            return toRunOn;
        }
    }

    public final InnerClass called = new InnerClass(this) {
        public final void execute() {
            incrementValue(); // This is what I thought should be throwing an error
        }
    };
}
```

However, while I would expect this to throw a compiler error in the `called` field defining `execute()` due to me not giving `incrementValue()` an object to work on (which is why I allowed for passing `this` to the inner class), it is completely fine with it. I'm uncertain why this is not giving me an error, and further confused as to what instance it *would* be calling on.

Am I misunderstanding some form of reference calling here, or is something more subtle going on?

Comment: An (non-static) inner class always has an implicit reference to the outter `this`. You're calling `SomeClass.this.incrementValue()` here. Cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731719/how-can-this-of-the-outer-class-be-accessed-from-an-inner-class

Comment: @zapl O.o Well that makes this a little more convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`called` is assigned an instance of an anonymous sub-class of `InnerClass`. Since it's an instance member, it is initialized when an instance of `SomeClass` is created.

Since it is declared in the body of `SomeClass`, it is an inner class of `SomeClass` and has access to the instance methods and members of `SomeClass`. `incrementValue()` will be executed on the instance of `SomeClass` for which the `called` member was initialized.

Perhaps it would be easier to understand if you replace the anonymous class with an equivalent regular inner class :

```
public class SomeClass {

    ....

    class SubInnerClass extends InnerClass {
        public final void execute() {
            incrementValue();
        }
    }

    public final InnerClass called = new SubInnerClass(this);

    ....
}
```