# How to Bind Json Data in Expandale List view?

Tags: java, android, json, expandablelistview

I want to Bind json Data to Expandable list view in Android.
The Following Error shown

Error:

```
Error:(175, 65) error: incompatible types: MainActivity.ExecuteTask cannot be converted to Context
```

Json Data:

```
    [{"PART_ID":"01684.021","SHIFT_DATE":"20-SEP-17","PLAN_QTY":"2","ACTUAL_QTY":"2"},
{"PART_ID":"0346001.020","SHIFT_DATE":"20-SEP-17","PLAN_QTY":"4","ACTUAL_QTY":"4"},
{"PART_ID":"01068.021","SHIFT_DATE":"20-SEP-17","PLAN_QTY":"7","ACTUAL_QTY":"7"}]
```

ExpandableListAdapter.java

```
package com.example.saravanakumars.expandable_listview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * Created by saravanakumars on 10/3/2017.
 */

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

//    ArrayList<TerbaruModel>ListTerbaru;
//    ArrayList<ArrayList<ChildTerbaru>> ListChildTerbaru;
//    int count;
    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.saravanakumars.expandable_listview;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;


    String s1 = "CLASIFICACION";
    String s2 = "ONE PIECE";
    String s3 = "159-OP SHERIDAN";


    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static String url = "http://113.193.30.155/MobileService/MobileService.asmx/GetPartbyProcessFamilyModel";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
//
//        // preparing list data
//        prepareListData();
//
//        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
//
//        // setting list adapter
//        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


        new ExecuteTask().execute(s1, s2, s3);


    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
//     */
//    private void prepareListData() {
//        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
//        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
//
//        // Adding child data
//        listDataHeader.add("Defect");
//        listDataHeader.add("Production");
//        listDataHeader.add("Report");
//
//        // Adding child data
//        List<String> Defect = new ArrayList<String>();
//        Defect.add("Defect-1");
//        Defect.add("Defect-2");
//        Defect.add("Defect-3");
//        Defect.add("Defect-4");
//        Defect.add("Defect-5");
//
//
//        List<String> Production = new ArrayList<String>();
//        Production.add("Production-1");
//        Production.add("Production-2");
//        Production.add("Production-3");
//        Production.add("Production-4");
//        Production.add("Production-5");
//
//
//        List<String> Report = new ArrayList<String>();
//        Report.add("Report-1");
//        Report.add("Report-2");
//        Report.add("Report-3");
//        Report.add("Report-4");
//        Report.add("Report-5");
//
//        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), Defect); // Header, Child data
//        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), Production);
//        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), Report);
//    }

    class ExecuteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String res = PostData(params);

            return res;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//                        result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
//                        .show();

            fetchResponse(result.replace("\n", "").trim());
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

        private void fetchResponse(String result) {
            if (!result.equals("")) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

                    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
                    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

                    // Adding child data
                    listDataHeader.add("SHIFT_DATE");
                    listDataHeader.add("PART_ID");
                    listDataHeader.add("PLAN_QTY");

                    // Adding child data
                    List<String> SHIFT_DATE = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        SHIFT_DATE.add(jsonObject.getString("SHIFT_DATE"));
                    }

                    List<String> PART_ID = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        PART_ID.add(jsonObject1.getString("PART_ID"));
                    }


                    List<String> PLAN_QTY = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        PLAN_QTY.add(jsonObject2.getString("PLAN_QTY"));
                    }

                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), SHIFT_DATE); // Header, Child data
                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), PART_ID);
                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), PLAN_QTY);

//
                        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

                    // setting list adapter
                    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


        public String PostData(String[] valuse) {
            String s = "";
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://113.193.30.155/MobileService/MobileService.asmx/GetPartbyProcessFamilyModel");

                List<BasicNameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
                list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("strProcess", s1));
                list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("strFamily", s2));
                list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("strModel", s3));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                s = readResponse(httpResponse);

//            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
//
//            s = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            } catch (Exception exception) {
            }
            return s;


        }

        public String readResponse(HttpResponse res) {
            InputStream is = null;
            String return_text = "";
            try {
                is = res.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line = "";
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                return_text = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return return_text;

        }

    }
}
```

Help me out in this .

Comment: Java's basics: what is `this` keyword and how it works ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can "this" of the outer class be accessed from an inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731719/how-can-this-of-the-outer-class-be-accessed-from-an-inner-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this :

```
listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this,listDataHeader,listDataChild);
```

to :

```
   listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
```

Comment: Log cat: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                Process: com.example.saravanakumars.expandable_listview, PID: 20712
                                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ProgressDialog.dismiss()' on a null object reference