# How to pass the context of some activity as an argument

Tags: android

I want to know how can I send the context of an activity from `ClassA.java` to `MainAddingItems.java`.

I can pass the `MainActivity.class` as the argument but I am not able to pass the context.

Here is some of the code of `ClassA` calling the constructor of `MainAddingItems`

`new MainAddingItems(MainActivity.class,"MainActivity Clicked",R.id.activity_main_linearLayout,"Profile Acitvity")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can "this" of the outer class be accessed from an inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731719/how-can-this-of-the-outer-class-be-accessed-from-an-inner-class)

Answer (score 0):

It will work ..make sure that you declerad it as public and static like below

Public static Context context ;
In your main activity

You can use any where that context in whole project

Comment: Do not do this. It is well known that `static` Context is the first source of memory leaks in `Android`. Even worse, reference it from outside the class...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. If your constructor is:

```
MainAddingItems(Context context) {...}
```

Then from `Activity1` you can just do:

```
Context context = Activity1.this; // Or getApplicationContext() or View.getContext() or whatever context you want


MainAddingItems(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are passing the context here . In android context is the current state of application . As an example if you are in a activity, then the context is the activity class itself , same for service and any other component of android

Let me give another example ,

Just try to show a toast message in `onCreate` method of any activity , considering your activity name is `SimpleActivity` you may write something like this

```
Toast.makeText(this "Understating context",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Or you may write the following

```
Toast.makeText(SimpleActivity.this "Understating context",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The first [parameter of](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)) `makeText` method  is `context` , and it works if you simply pass the class .

This is how you will pass activity as an argument

```
public SimpleClass{
  AppCompatActivity mActivity;

  public SimpleClass(AppCompatActivity mActivity){
      this.mActivity = mActivity;
  }
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SimpleClass newSimpleClass = new SimpleClass(MainActivity.this);

    }
}
```

Comment: Then how can I pass an activity as an argument ?

Answer (score 0):

Make your MainAddingItem class's constructor as this,

```
class MainAddingItem {
Context context;

MainAddingItem (Context context, rest of the parameters){
this.context = context;
}
}
```

Use the above constructor and pass the activity's context in the constructor's parameter.

```
new MainAddingItem (this, rest of the parameters);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make Context as static like in MainActivity.

Public static Context  contextToUse;

You can use like below : 
 MainActivity.contextToUse

Please let me know ,if it is helpful to you

Comment: No, `context` shouldn't be stored in a static variable and Android Studio will point this out.

Comment: Please check below link 
 https ://itekblog.com/android-context-in-non-activity-class/